# Do stronger emotions take longer to process with dreams?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, emotion, dreams

[One theory](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6428732) of dreams is they help us process strong experiences. So I wondered whether one needs a longer sleep after some strong experiences partly to give the brain longer to complete the healing/rewiring process.